# Build and deploy wpf in visual studio 2010 with database

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, orm

I know `WPF`. I want to start a small `WPF App` that will interact with database (`SQL Server`). I know how to develop it locally but I am worried about deployment. Client machine don't have `.Net` or `SQL Server`. Client OS may be `Windows XP` or `Windows 7`. What `ORM` should I use? How to add `Database` in my project? `edmx`, `service-based databse`??  or something other?

Answer (score 0):

As part of your deployment, you can add .Net framework and SQL server as pre-requisites. Either you can bundle the .Net framework installer and SQl installer in your application installer or provide valid web-links to the user from where they can download and install them.

Now regarding ORM, better to go with Entity Framework as you are using SQL server. I would suggest go for code first approach. Entity framework is a nuget package that you can add reference in your project.

Comment: thanks for your reply. How can I bundle `.Net Framework Installer` and `SQL Installer`?

Comment: In case you are creating the installer using Installshield, you can add pre-requisites in it.

Comment: I dont want my client to install prerequisites seperately